# Регистрация на PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

Есть задача - это регистрация пользователя и сохранение его в базе phpmyadmin. При отправке GET или POST запросом в form нужно обязательно жать отправить. После этого идёт обновление страницы. Только после этого можно отослать пользователю инфу о том что допустим такой ник или email уже есть в базе. Такой подход не устраивает. Нужна другая реализация при которой пользователь только вписал свой ник и email в поле[image: введите сюда описание изображения] (он ещё не нажимал отправить) и ему сразу же выведется что такой ник уже занят. Это по типу реализации регистрации на mail.ru . Можно ли такое реализовать в php в принципе ? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Идея не плохая, но устарела лет так на 10))) Теперь это выглядит лишь как удобный инструмент для парсинга вашей БД))) Пусть данные и не особо секретные, но вот я бы не хотел, чтобы кто-то знал ВСЕ ники пользователей с моего магазина... Тем более что половина придумывает ник один в один с емайлом))) Ну а насчет обновления страницы - ну так аджакс же есть!!

Comment: речь идёт всего лишь о тестовой версии, речь о бд вообще в данном вопросе не идёт.

Answer (score 1):

С использованием JS можно.

Например:

Клиент:

```js
myPerfectEmailInput.addEventListener("change", e => {
  if (!e.target.value.match(/@/) || e.target.value.length < 4)
    return false; // дабы лишний раз сервер не дёргать.
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("email", e.target.value); // вдруг ещё что-то передать нужно.

  fetch("/url/to/handler.php", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData
    })
    .then(r => r.json()) // подразумевается, что ответ с сервера - JSON
    .then(r => {
      if (r.emailExists) {
        doSomething(); // например, выдаём какую-нибудь ошибку/подсвечиваем инпут красным или что-то в этом духе.
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<input type="email" id="myPerfectEmailInput" />
```

PHP:
`$result = $db->query("SELECT 1 AS exists FROM users WHERE email = ?", $_POST['email']); // здесь какой-то запрос в БД. 
echo json_encode(["emailExists" => $result["exists"]);`

Работать может примерно [так](https://demo.ymer.xyz/stack/870117.php). (если что, занят или не занят - рандом, просто для примера)

UPD. Добавил также проверку на количество символов, сам об этом не подумал. Спасибо [Сергею](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/203315/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%92).

Comment: Добавлю - желательно лимитировать запросы, т.е. не посылать на сервер запрос для каждой буквы, а ждать пока не наберут 3-4-5 символов. Просто представьте, что к вам на сайт в массовом порядке пришли в гости боты и начали вписывать текст в форму, сервер скажет спасибо или нет? Все равно практической пользы от этого нет, кто захочет зарегистрироваться, тот захочет, а кто пошалить - тот будет отсечен лимитом.

Comment: @СергейВ., правил ответ, спасибо.